# filter table with jquery gives a bad result

Tags: jquery, html

I need to filter the table by title,  when writing the title in textBox, the list table is filtered and results in disorderliness and bad format.

Here is my code:

template.html

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
         ... all src
</head>
<body>
        <script src="{% static 'videoclub/js/search.js' %}"></script>


<h1 id="searchTitle">Search a movie</h1>

    <div class="table-wrapper">

        <div class="container">

                <td>
                    <label for="title">Search by title</label>
                    <input  type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" >

                </td>

                <td>
                    <label for="director">Search by Director</label>
                    <input type="text" id="director" placeholder="Director" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label for="years">Choose a year</label>
                      <select class="form-control-sm ml-1 w-40" id="years"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" id="searchButton" value="Search Movie">
                </td>
        </div>

        <table   class="table table-striped table-hover" id="list-movie" >

            <thead>
               <td> LIST OF MOVIES</td>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tableBody">
                <!--película description-->
                {% for movie in allMovies %}

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" ROWSPAN="4">
                          <img width="100" height="" src="{% static movie.movie_url_cover %}" alt="Pulp Fiction ">
                        </td>

                        <td abbr="red" ><font color="#B40431" size="3"> {{movie.movie_title}} ({{movie.movie_year}})</font></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>{{movie.movie_rating}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td><font color="#084B8A" size="2">{{movie.movie_director}}</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="#585858" size="1">{{movie.movie_actors}}</font></td>
                    </tr>

                {% endfor %}
                <!--   ******    -->

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

search.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#tableBody  tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

At first, the table list contains all the movies in the correct format but when filtered, the format is not accurate any idea??? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: And how is this a python/ django exactly ???

Comment: already change the tags sorry.. django for the template tags in html

Comment: thanks - but even the django tag is irrelevant, you'd have the very same issue with plain static HTML.

Comment: You have multiple `<tr>` for one record, you should do filtering `server-side` or change the logic of your search in `jquery` to match your table's rows structure

Comment: Inspect your html code with and without filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this   search by title & search by director works see live example

https://codepen.io/vkv88/pen/eYpzxPp?editors=1010

i made the `tbody` inside the for loop of the Twig Template
also gave director TD & title TD classNames

```
                {% for movie in allMovies %}
            <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" ROWSPAN="4">
                          <img width="100" height="" src="{{movie.movie_url_cover}}" alt="Description ">
                        </td>

                        <td abbr="red" class="title"><font color="#B40431" size="3"> {{movie.movie_title}} ({{movie.movie_year}})</font></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>{{movie.movie_rating}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                     <td class="dircetor"><font color="#084B8A" size="2">{{movie.movie_director}}</font></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><font color="#585858" size="1">{{movie.movie_actors}}</font></td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>

                {% endfor %}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input#title,input#director").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    input = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#list-movie tbody").hide();
    $("#list-movie tbody")
      .filter(function () {
        return (
          $(this)
            .find("." + input)
            .text()
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(value) > -1
        );
      })
      .show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are trying to toggle just the row inside table which displays the movie title and not the entire block for the movie details

A better way to handle this is to restructure the html to create nested table type structure and assigning the id of the nested table element as the movie title as below

```html
<tbody id="tableBody">
    <!--película description-->
    {% for movie in allMovies %}
      <tr>
        <table id="{{ movie.movie_title }}">
          <tr>
              <td align="center" ROWSPAN="4">
                <img width="100" height="" src="{% static movie.movie_url_cover %}" alt="Pulp Fiction ">
              </td>

              <td abbr="red" ><font color="#B40431" size="3"> {{movie.movie_title}} ({{movie.movie_year}})</font></td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
              <td>{{movie.movie_rating}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td><font color="#084B8A" size="2">{{movie.movie_director}}</font></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td><font color="#585858" size="1">{{movie.movie_actors}}</font></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <!--   ******    -->
```

---

once you make the above change in layout and adjust the styling, you can apply the filter on table based on id attribute and toggle the display like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#title").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#tableBody  tr > table").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).attr("id").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code is doing is, it only filters rows of image and movie name. The other rows like movie rating, movie director, movie actors gets completely ignored. So you need change your template in proper and advisable manner.

First of all,

Your one movie details should be in one row not in multiple rows, so try and convert it in one row

And add class to movie-name `td`, for ease of filtering

Like

```
<tr>
   <td align="center" ROWSPAN="4">
      <img width="100" height="" src="{% static movie.movie_url_cover %}" alt="Pulp Fiction ">
   </td>

    <td abbr="red" class="movie-name"><font color="#B40431" size="3"> {{movie.movie_title}} ({{movie.movie_year}})</font></td>

    <td>{{movie.movie_rating}}</td>

    <td><font color="#084B8A" size="2">{{movie.movie_director}}</font></td>

    <td><font color="#585858" size="1">{{movie.movie_actors}}</font></td>
</tr>
```

Now while filtering, just change logic to something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#title").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#tableBody  tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this.find('.movie-name')).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

This code will look for movie-name class and compare text of it, and then filter the row